# Headphone amplifier is humming

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, coupling

I have built headphone amplifier kit and connected it to the output of DVD player. It works but I can hear humming. The humming is present only when DVD is connected. There is no groundig of the boxes of the DVD and the amplifier. In my opinion the problem is in the input stage of the amplifier where the first part is potentiometer and the current flows inside. Please, how can I redesign the schematics to have a capacitor the first component in the signal flow (keeping the op-amp inverting)? Can I remove capacitor C13?

[image: input stage of the amplifier]

Comment: I don't think swapping the capacitor and the potentiometer will change anything

Comment: How do you power this circuit?

Comment: I am using transformer with two secondary windings, graetz rectifier bridge and 7815 + 7915.

Comment: @azrael How much capacitance is there on the input and output of the voltage regulators? Perhaps you could add that part of the circuit diagram to the question.

Comment: @AndrewMorton 100uF input and 10uF output.

Comment: @azrael There is a simple process to help you track down the exact source of the problem. (Which you need to know before taking on a solution to it.) The hum is quite often due to the lead resistance (which often just means using a cable using conductors with less resistance to help, but not eliminate the problem.) But a good process involves making yourself a small male/female module with the ground shells directly connected but the center points bypassed with a 1k resistor to the ground shell. No signal can get through this insertable module. But you can do a lot with it as a tool.

Comment: @azrael For example, just disconnect the cable and plug the module into your amplifier input. If things don't quiet down, then it's not a ground loop problem and there's something going on in your amplifier that needs to be figured out. Otherwise, if quiet with only that dummy plug there, now connect your source to the back end of the dummy module. If the output is not quiet then your amplifier has a problem on the center pin. If it is still quiet then disconnect the source and now put your cable directly on the amplifier and put the dummy on the other end (to test the cable.) Etc.

Answer (score 1):

You likely have ground loop hum, a common affliction with unbalanced connections.  You can easily mitigate it significantly by inserting a "hum break" resistor.  In the given circuit, you'd cut the ground line (if the design is accommodating, a scalpel will work out) and insert this 10 Ohm resistor (metal film).

To the left of the cut there should be the ground line coming from the amp (if necessary, this may require an isolated input jack), the ground line of the pot, and the ground line of the RC combination at the positive input of the Opamp.

This creates a poor man's balanced amplifier where common mode hum on input line and ground is not amplified but passes through without amplification (which renders it mostly dead in comparison to the signal).  In addition, breaking up the ground loop with the 10Ohms resistor means that any induced circular voltage meets resistance that stops it from inducing large currents, and the point where the voltage stacks up is mostly compensated for.

Now this strategy is for input stages with sizable amplification.  Here you have an amplification of -1 which would just make the hum pass through with different polarity.  So what you do is split your reference input half and half between this separated input ground and the system ground.  It may be a bit of a problem that the amplification is not actually -1 but depends on the wiper position.  With a circuit like this, it is unlikely that you'll overload the input stage, so it would make sense to move the volume control to after the Opamp.  The amplification factor still depends on the source impedance but at least not on the wiper position then.

With regard to input device safety (for things like electrical guitars), the 10Ohms is low enough to reliably trigger a GFCI switch but not much more.

So it depends on whether the grounding/earthing is part of a safety strategy whether you should even think about divvying up a ground line like that.  One can also add back conditional earthing through a high-current bridge amplifier that will start conducting at 1.2V of voltage difference when wired correctly.  It must be dimensioned to survive for long enough to blow/trigger the mains fuse.

Comment: Ok. I found the solution schematics on the internet. I will try it.

Comment: I have tried placing 22 ohm resistor (I don't have 10 ohm one) to the shielding between cable and input connector and there is no improvement. But I discovered that when I disconnect cable shielding the hum is enormous and music is very quiet.

Comment: I've described where to insert that resistor.  Between cable and input connector reduces the ground loop current but lets all the induced voltage stack up where it does the worst damage.  That's useless.  You need to include the reference voltage on the Opamp.  I've overlooked something else though and will make an edit.

Comment: Unfortunately the routing on PCB is made the way it is not possible to place resistor as described. Ground loop is created by current flow trought the shielding. Is this problem caused by the potentiometer at the input?